# Spring @ModelAttribute not working

Tags: spring-mvc, modelattribute

I have a controller in which I put both the get and post methods. Both methods work fine but when I introduce @ModelAttribute annotation to the POST method, it starts giving me Status 400 -- The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

I do not know what I am doing wrong. The View looks like:

```
<form:form method="post" action="createIdeaPublic" commandName="idea">
    <table class="form">
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><label for="title">Idea Title</label></td><td align="left"><form:input type="text" path="title" id="title"></form:input></td>
            <td align="right"><label for="email">Your Email</label></td><td align="left"><form:input type="text" path="requestorEmail" id="requestorEmail" class="emails"></form:input></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td align="right"><label for="partnerEmail">CI Contact Email</label></td><td align="left"><form:input type="text" path="cIInitialContact" id="cIInitialContact" class="emails"></form:input></td>
            <td align="right"><label for="sponsorEmail">Sponsor Email</label></td><td align="left"><form:input type="text" path="sponsorEmail" id="sponsorEmail" class="emails"></form:input></td>

        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td align="right"><label for="requestedDeliveryDate">Requested Delivery Date</label></td><td align="left"><form:input type="text" path="requestedDeliveryDate" id="requestedDeliveryDate" class="datepicker"></form:input></td>
            <td align="right"><label>Classification</label></td><td align="left">

                <label for="discretionary" class="radio">Discretionary</label>
                <form:radiobutton path="stateDescription" id="discretionary" value="Discretionary"></form:radiobutton>
                <label for="mandatory" class="radio">Mandatory</label>
                <form:radiobutton path="stateDescription" id="mandatory" value="Mandatory"></form:radiobutton>
                <label for="regulatory" class="radio">Regulatory</label>
                <form:radiobutton path="stateDescription" id="regulatory" value="Regulatory"></form:radiobutton>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="right"><input type="submit" class="ui ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" style="margin-top: .6em; margin-right: 1em;font-weight: bold;font-size: 1.2em; width: 150px;" value="Create Idea" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

I tried changing the commandName="idea" to modelAttribute="idea" but no benifit.

The Spring controller looks like

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping ("/createIdeaPublic")
public class CreateIdeaPublicController{


   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView view(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("areas",Utils.areas);
      return new ModelAndView("createIdeaPublic", "idea", new Idea());
   }


   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String submit(@ModelAttribute("idea")Idea idea, ModelMap model) {

//     System.out.println(idea.getTitle());
       System.out.println("Hello World");
      return "redirect:createIdeaPublic";
   }

}
```

But as soon as I remove the ***@ModelAttribute("idea")Idea idea,*** from the submit method, the form submission starts working.

Comment: Can you add the exception stacktrace from the server ?

Comment: It doesn't throw any exceptions either.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was issue with the date field. If I dont enter a value into the date field, I would get 400 page. So here is what I did in the Controller class. Copy as it is if you have this issue (Just change the date format accordingly).

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);

        // true passed to CustomDateEditor constructor means convert empty String to null
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
    }
```